# Meteor Project Structure with Routing - error there is already a collection named person

Tags: mongodb, meteor, routes, include

I am struggling to get my project to work with Routing, I imagine that something is really wrong.

currently the exception being logged

```
Error: There is already a collection named "person"
    at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:240:15)
    at meteorInstall.collections.persons.js (collections/persons.js:2:23)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:197:9)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:120:16)
    at /home/usr/Dev/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/app.js:198:1
    at /home/usr/Dev/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:303:34
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/usr/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.3_2.7s3fq6++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /home/usr/Dev/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
    at /home/usr/Dev/simple-todos/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:352:5
Exited with code: 1
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

Following are my code:

**routes.js** (Loaded in the lib folder so that it loads first)

```
Router.configure({
   layoutTemplate: 'layout'
 });

Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('personTemplate');
});
```

**Main Layout** Template (to be the container for the entire App) + a yield container to direct the routes on the main template.

```
<template name="layout">
    <nav class="deep-orange lighen-4" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-wrapper container left">
            <ul class="right">
                <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">about</a></li>
                {{> loginButtons}}
                <!-- <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:30px;color:grey">person</i> -->
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo left ">SiteName</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
  {{> yield}}
</template>
```

person.js (the collection definition file -- also located in the lib folder to load first)

```
import {mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
export const Person = new Mongo.Collection('person');
```

The **personTemplate** definition

```
<template name="personTemplate">
    {{#each person}}
    {{> todosTest}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="todosTest">
    <ul>{{name}}</ul>
</template>
```

**person helpers** - which will perform the lookup to the person collection

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Person } from '../../lib/collections/persons.js';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import '../templates/personTemplate.html';

Template.personTemplate.helpers({
  person(){
    var aPerson = Person.find({});
    // check for existence before returning
    return aPerson && aPerson.name
  }
});
```

lastly my **main.js** file to load the collection on the server:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import '../lib/collections/persons.js';
```

below a graphic to display the folder layout:

[image]

Comment: Fixed the Issue - but there is a load sequence error, it would seem! --

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining the collections 'Person' twice by having the same file in two different folders.

Comment: aargh! .. how did I not notice that?  --- still crashing though -- Exception in template helper: require<.client.helpers["personHelpers.js"]</<.person@http://localhost:3000